# AS400 RPGLE/free dynamic variables in operations

Tags: variables, dynamic, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I'm fairly certain after years of searching that this is not possible, but I'll ask anyway.

The question is whether it's possible to use a dynamic variable in an operation when you don't know the field name.  For example, I have a data structure that contains a few hundred fields.  The operator selects one of those fields and the program needs to know what data resides in the field from the data structure passed.  So we'll say that there are 100 fields, and field50 is what the operator chose to operate on.  The program would be passed in the field name (i.e. field50) in the FLDNAM variable.  The program would read something like this the normal way:

```
/free
  if field50 = 'XXX'
  // do something
  endif;
/end-free
```

The problem is that I would have to code this 100 times for every operation.  For example:

```
/free
  if fldnam = 'field1';
  // do something
  elseif fldnam = 'field2';
  // do something
  ..
  elseif fldnam = 'field50';
  // do something
  endif;
```

Is there any possible way of performing an operation on a field not yet known?  (i.e. IF FLDNAM(pointer data) = 'XXX' then do something)

Comment: RPG is a strongly typed language. Fields must be defined in advance, and the name of the field is never known to the program in a way that you can retrieve or specify dynamically. Could you use an array, or are the fields all different?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the response.I thought about using an array if required, just for faster processing.  I would be getting into loading a data area as well as a field name array, and then a positional array as well.  The code could become quite complicated maintenance wise, but that's my backup plan if you can't use dynamic variables.  All fields are different lengths, some are packed decimal, etc.  I know it is possible to make it work through arrays, but figured I'd check and see if there are any other options.

Comment: Absolutely this could be done.  Think of a query.  Does it know what fields you want before you start?  Can it help you select the fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data structure is externally-described and you know what file it comes from, you could use the QUSLFLD API to find out the offset, length, and type of the field in the data structure, and then use substring to get the data and then use other calculations to get the value, depending on the data type.

Comment: I added this as an answer, even though REXX could probably do it.  I ended up going with a solution similar to this one however.  I already have a file that lists positions of data, lengths, etc.  Basically is just a DSPFFD of the file in question.  I'm loading those values into arrays, and piecing out the data on the fly and replacing it based on the field sent to the program.  It turned out to be easier than I thought and a lot less code than I imagined.  Good thing, cause I'm too old to learn another programming language.  :)

Comment: Too old? I learned Algol60 in '70 used 5 years, Cobol in '75 25y, Easytrieve in 76, 10y, Pl1 in '77 8y, Fortran in '80 2y, EasytrievePlus in '86, 10y, Rpg3 in 2001 3y, VisualBasic '04 10y, RpgIle '11 3y. Did some Datacom/Ideal, DL/1, VaxSql, Cics/Db2, Sql-server. Need more?: being a pensionado, learn Python to understand a book about AI, C++ for my Arduino, c# for audioprojects. I must be more than old then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, no.

RPG's simply not designed for that.  Few languages are.

You may want to look at scripting languages.  Perl for instance, can evaluate on the fly.  REXX, which comes installed on the IBM i, has an `INTERPRET` keyword.

[REXX Reference manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/books_web/sc415729.pdf)