# AS400 RPGLE/free embedded SQL against data structure

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

I am wondering if it's possible to do an SQL against a data structure, instead of a file.

For example, I have an external data structure with 100 fields, lets say the naming convention is field1, field2, etc.....The data structure name is DS1.  The DS1 structure is passed in to the program with all 100 fields containing values. I am wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

```
/free
  exec sql                 
  update DS1 set field1 = field2;  
/end-free
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to query a data structure instead of going to disk to an actual file, but if it is it would make things a little faster and simpler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, no.

Closest thing to what you're asking for is with the `VALUES INTO` statement.

```
 d myDS            ds                  qualified
 d  fld1                         10a
 d  fld2                         10a


  /free
    myDS.fld1 = 'HELLO';
    exec sql
       values (:myDS.fld1) into :myds.fld2;

    dsply myDS.fld2;
    *INLR = *ON;
    return;
  /end-free
```

Why you'd want to do that is beyond me when a simple `myDS.fld2 = myDS.fld1;` is sufficient. I assume it has to do with your other question: [AS400 RPGLE/free dynamic variables in operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876465/as400-rpgle-free-dynamic-variables-in-operations)

Comment: You are correct.  It did have to do with that other question.  I like to make things more automatic.  We have a lot of real time data going through various batch jobs that perform different functions.  Often, we have to write a program when a customer wants a field set differently.  So you end up with 1 program that it's only function is to set a field to "A" instead of "B" when field10 is set to "ABC" or whatever.  I'm trying to create one program that reads a user defined script file and sets the field based on that instead of having multiple programs performing just one thing.